# Form TextField widget issue, The Form is sending data which is onScreen on submit is pressed

Tags: flutter, firebase, get

i am simply adding and showing Questions From Firestore Database,

I am adding Question in my Firestore Database, Every Textfield is getting updated in firestore database but the top 2 Textfield are returning no value, in my database it shows+

QuestionId:      "",

QuestionText:     ""

All other fields field show data which was filled at the time of submission.

here is my code :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/data_controller.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/models/comman_dailog.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/models/product_image_picker.dart';

class AddQuestionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AddQuestionScreen> createState() => _AddQuestionScreenState();
}

class _AddQuestionScreenState extends State<AddQuestionScreen> {
  DataController controller = Get.find();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  Map<String, dynamic> AddQuestionData = {
    "QuestionId": "",
    "QuestionText": "",
    "AnswerA": "",
    "AnswerB": "",
    "AnswerC": "",
    "AnswerD": "",
    "AskedIn": "",
    "SubjectName": "",
    "ChapterName": "",
    "CorrectAnswer": "",
  };
  var _userImageFile;

  void _pickedImage(File image) {
    _userImageFile = image;
  }

  addProduct() {
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      controller.addNewQuestion(AddQuestionData, _userImageFile);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('[Admin Only]Add New Question'),
      ),
      body: Card(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ProductImagePicker(_pickedImage),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'QuestionId ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'QustionId Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['QuestionId'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter Question : QuestinonText ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'QuestionText Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['QuestionText'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Answer A ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Answer A Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['AnswerA'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Answer B ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'AnswerB Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['AnswerB'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Answer C ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'AnswerC Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['AnswerC'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'AnswerD ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'AnswerD Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['AnswerD'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'AskedIn ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'AskedIn Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['AskedIn'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'SubjectName ?  [Proper Spelling is Required]',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'SubjectName Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['SubjectName'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'ChapterName ?  [Proper Spelling is Required]',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'ChapterName Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['ChapterName'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'CorrectAnswer ?  ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'CorrectAnswer Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['CorrectAnswer'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: addProduct,
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define TextEditingController instance like below inside the widget class.

```
final textController1 = TextEditingController()
final textController2 = TextEditingController()
final textController3 = TextEditingController()
```

and set as value of controller. Do it for others too.

```
                TextFormField(
                  controller: textController1,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'QuestionId ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'QustionId Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['QuestionId'] = textController1.text.trim();
                  },
                ),
TextFormField(
controller: textController2,
...
```

Comment: I did this, when i type something in first field all field are getting filled by same data(before Submit), I think problem is in Validate..

Comment: you need to create more textControllers and pass it to each TextField.

Comment: I have updated my answer. try and confirm.

Comment: if it works. please upvote and select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Created 10 Controllers

```
  final textController1 = TextEditingController();
  final textController2 = TextEditingController();
  final textController3 = TextEditingController();
  final textController4 = TextEditingController();
  final textController5 = TextEditingController();
  final textController6 = TextEditingController();
  final textController7 = TextEditingController();
  final textController8 = TextEditingController();
  final textController9 = TextEditingController();
  final textController10 = TextEditingController();
```

doing this for all form fields

```
TextFormField(
                  controller: textController1,    // value of each TextController is different... in 2nd form field used different controller.
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'QuestionId ? ',
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'QustionId Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    AddQuestionData['QuestionId'] = textController1.text.trim();    // same thing followed here also.
                  },
                ),
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Declare as follows:

```
final textController = TextEditingController();
```

And then use it in `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
   controller: textController,
..
)
```